# Using LUT in OpenGLES shader for false coloring

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader, glsles

I am trying to use a fragment shader to convert a grayscale image to colored output. The idea is fairly straightforward; make three arrays of length 256 and map greyscale values [0,255] to RGB (3 * [0,255]). Below is the code I've written:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;

const int red[256] = int[256](255, 128, 240, ... , 143); // declaring as const/non-const changes the output
const int green[256] = int[256](230, 120, 34, ... , 100);
const int blue[256] = int[256](90, 73, 99, ... , 42);

void main (void) {
    float r, g, b, y;
    y = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord).r; // using only the r value from YUV received
    y = y * 255.0; // convert y from [0,1] to [0,255]

    int index = int(y); // use y as an index to map value to the lookup arrays

    r = float(red[index]) / 255.0;
    g = float(green[index]) / 255.0;
    b = float(blue[index]) / 255.0;

    // Set the RGB color of our pixel
    gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0); 
    // here, if I were to instead assign gl_FragColor = vec4(y,y,y, 1.0); I'd see the expected greyscale output
}
```

I'm fairly new to OpenGL, but I've been able to use simple equations and get a false-colored output, the code for which looks something as follows:

```
y = y * 255;
r = y * 0.47446 + 0.65658;
g = y * 0.16213 + 0.58145;
b = y * 0.047524+ 0.75203;
gl_FragColor = vec4(r / 255.0, g / 255.0, b / 255.0, 1.0);
```

The output using the LUT however is fairly bizarre. Declaring the int arrays as `const` gives only the 0th index and 255th index's output; no color from in between. Without the `const` the code crashes with a`SIGSEGV`.

Has anyone else attempted this / know what I may be doing wrong in the LUT code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but the more traditional way to do this is to store the LUT as a 256x1 texture, and just do a texture lookup.

```
void main (void) {
    float luminance = texture2D(inputTexture, vTextureCoord).r;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(lutTexture, vec2(luminance, 0.5));
}
```

... is probably going to be a lot faster and more flexible.

Comment: I'm fairly new to gles. I can make a 256x1 texture and pass it from CPU to GL, but what does the `vec2(lum,0.5)` line do? Can you give a more robust answer?

Comment: You need a 2 dimensional texture coordinate to make a texture lookup, so `vec2(lum, 0.5)` uses the luminance value from the original data as the x coordinate, and fixed 0.5 as the y coordinate. Texture coordinates are between 0.0 and 1.0, so you don't need to worry about the resolution of the inputs - it will all "just work".